# I'd like to note a tag in my [notebook] that seems to have reappeared

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I recently noticed that the [notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notebook) tag was created (about 4 hours ago as I'm typing this question).  Oddly, though, it has 12 followers, and the one question (referring to SQL notebooks) that uses it has only 15 views.  This leads me to think that the tag used to exist, was deleted or renamed, and has now come back, inheriting all its old followers.  (There is no tag wiki.)

I did a search and did not find any sort of burninate request on the tag.  So I'm wondering:  Was this tag previously purged?  Should it be removed again?

Comment: It's gone now, will be automatically deleted when the daily dead tag removal script runs. Then it can only be recreated by those with greater than 1500 rep.

Comment: Keep in mind that when a tag disappears, that tag does not get removed from the watched tags list of any users and, in fact, users can type in any tag they'd like into their favorites, even if they don't currently exist. It's not so much inheriting anything as just detecting how many people already have it in their favorites for whatever reason.

Comment: The tag doesn't appear to have been (officially) burned before.